# Java objects validation in spring without annotations

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm working with mybatis to perform all database actions. I'm also working with an Angular front-end, so the validations in the client are made with `angular-validation-ghiscoding` and the native HTML5 validations. I would like to validate the data in the bank-end to, but I don't want to use annotations.

Here is an example of the code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = SecureApiResources.URI_UPDATE_ACCOUNT, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Account updateAccount(
            @RequestBody final AccountRequestUpdate accountRequest) { // Object to be validated (accountRequest)

        Account account = accountMapper.getAccountOfMerchant(authContextHolder.getMerchantId(), authContextHolder.getDefaultAccountId());

        if (account == null) {
            HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
                    SecureApiResources.ERROR_ACCOUNTS_NOT_FOUND);
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
        }
        int resultUpdate;
        try {
            // In this point I should validate the accountRequest object
            account.setAccountName(accountRequest.getAccountName());
            account.setCommercialName(accountRequest.getCommerciaName());
            account.setCountry(accountRequest.getCountry());
            account.setCity(accountRequest.getCity());
            resultUpdate = accountMapper.updateMerchant(account);
            if (resultUpdate == 0) {
                HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
                        SecureApiResources.ERROR_ACCOUNTS_NOT_FOUND);
                throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
                    SecureApiResources.ERROR_SQL_NOT_EXECUTE);
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
        }

        return account;
    }
```

In the same class I have a method to create an account and I reciebe another model object (`AccountRequestCreate accountRequest`).

Which could be the most recommended option to implement without xml neither annotations?

Comment: Ironically, the most recommend approach is using `@Valid` or `@validated` annotations! What's the problem of annotations? You've already added a `@RequestBody`, i guess you can make room for one more annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recommended approach is using `@Valid` or `@Validated` annotations but since you're not totally OK with that, you can `Autowire` the `javax.validation.Validator` into your controller and perform the validation manually:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
    @Autowired private Validator validator;

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public ResponseEntity<?> someHandler(@RequestBody SomeBody body) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeBody>> violations = validator.validate(body);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> messages = violations
                                   .stream()
                                   .map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(messages);
        }
        // the rest of controller
    }
}
```

With this approach, you will repeat the validation logic in all other controllers which is, well, not a good idea. Also you're violating the `DRY` principle.

As i said it's better to annotate your bean with `@Valid` or `@Validated`:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<?> someHandler(@RequestBody @Valid SomeBody body) { ... }
```

If passed bean violates at least one validation rule, an `MethodArgumentNotValidException` would be thrown. For handling that exception you can write a `ControllerAdvice` that catches the exception and return a suitable HTTP response, say a `400 Bad Request`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
         List<String> validationErrors = ex.getBindingResult()
                                            .getAllErrors()
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(ObjectError::getDefaultMessage)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

         return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(validatioErrors);
    }
}
```